# Stored procedure creation using MySqlConnector 2.0.0 fails

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

I'm trying to upgrade `MySqlConnector` from 0.60.3 to 2.0.0

Here is the text I use for `CommandText`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc(OUT p_out INT) 
BEGIN
  SET p_out = 1;
  SELECT 200;
END;
```

Here is the error message I receive:

```
(0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

As far as I understand, my syntax is correct according to this documentation:

https://mysqlconnector.net/troubleshooting/delimiter/

UPDATE:

It turns out that my method fails on `MySqlCommand.Prepare()` which I'm calling manually. Without this call, ExecuteNonQuery() works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `MySqlCommand.Prepare()` function is used to make a prepared statement out of a specific command text.

But you should check the [MySQL prepared statements documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.html) and realize that prepared statements do not make sense in what you are trying to do.

Prepared statements make sense in DML (Data Manipulation Language) queries but your command text is DDL (Data Definition Language).